# Optaplanner CVRPTW example clarification

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to understand the Optaplanner CVRPTW example and have the below questions:

1. Does every node require both distance and travel time to every other node? Or it just requires any one of them? Example data set does not contain both of them. I think it uses euclidean formula to calculate the distance, but how does it automatically calculate travel time?
2. Is it possible to use real time data (precalculated road distance data)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends if the dataset is using `AirLocation` or `RoadLocation`. See docs on vehicle routing, chapter 3.

[image]

2. Yes, if you can hold all the data in memory. At 10k+ locations this becomes a problem because (10k)² ints require almost 2GB RAM. The goal of `SegmentedRoadLocation` is to scale up to 100k locations without using a lot of RAM, but generating good segmented road location has proven to be difficult.

Comment: I want to develop CVRPTW using RoadLocation and customers are not more than 500. Do we need to input distance or travel time (or both) to Optaplanner?  I am already passing ready time, due time and service time (in seconds) for each customer.